# Can I disable the animated text responses in ChatGPT?

Tags: chatgpt

I understand that performing inference on a large language model takes time, which is why ChatGPT does not respond instantly. ChatGPT's responses appear on the screen at a few words per second using a typewriter effect. However, according to ChatGPT, the underlying technology does not generate responses sequentially:

> GPT models generate responses in a more parallel manner rather than sequentially. The animation you see is likely designed to give the illusion of a more conversational experience, even though it does not accurately represent the way the AI generates responses.

Thus, I expect that before my browser can locally animate the first word of ChatGPT's response, it receives a complete response from the ChatGPT backend. This would allow me to speed up the UI with a client-side bookmarklet. I used the Firefox debug tools to test this idea, and saw that when I send a message which prompts ChatGPT to respond, Firefox POSTs a JSON object containing my message and a conversation ID to `https://chat.openai.com/backend-api/conversation`.

Rather than receiving a complete response immediately, followed by an animation that plays out over 30+ seconds, I found that the POST request remained open for the whole period while the "animation" was playing. And if I use the element inspector on the "animated" paragraph, I can see that the underlying text content is being changed – it doesn't look like a CSS animation. Also, I can't see the response the API sent my browser. I can see that the response type was `text/event-stream`, but the Response tab just says "No messages for this request."

What's going on here? How is ChatGPT creating the "animation" and how can I use the debug tools to view the server-sent events? Is it possible to get faster responses from ChatGPT using a client-side bookmarklet? Is the ChatGPT backend simulating a sequential response to manage demand, or giving me incorrect information about how its own responses are generated?

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps.  Questions about internal policies, technologies, & algorithms of web app companies are  [off-topic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as are bookmarklets. The focus on code may make it a candidate for Stack Overflow but review their [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  This article on **Meta Stack Exchange** may be helpful: [Which computer science/programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632 "https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632")

Comment: See [Why does ChatGPT not give the answer text all at once?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38923/42632) (from [ai.se])

Comment: This question is not a practical, detailed question about using a web application. By the other hand, it has other problems lack asking, it requires more focus. Questions about web browser developer tools might be on-topic in [su], [so] and probably other sites. Questions about non-public APIs might be on-topic in [reverseengineering.se]. Questions about public using public APIs might be ontopic in [so]. Some questions about how ChatGPT works might be on-topic in [ai.se].

Comment: It is possible to disable the animation (no bookmarklet/code needed!), and I can explain how if @Rubén or Blind Spots would reopen the question. However, I'm not sure that disabling it actually speeds up the response.

Comment: @Laurel , It's unclear how your comment explains why the question should not be closed. Please elaborate. Ref [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions),

Comment: @Rubén Given the close reason, it's unclear why the question should be closed. From the link: "Why can't I ask customer service-related questions? Because we don't know the answer." I know the answer. There was no reverse engineering needed but rather just changing one simple setting. No further details needed in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please flag the question for moderation attention. Remember that the text box should clearly state what is being asked and why this flag is being used. If there is not enough space, you can leave out the part requesting that another mod review the flag; I will let my fellow mods handle it.